# Abrindo um banco de dados no SQLite ao invés de criar no Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite

Olá, gostaria da ajuda de vocês, se existe uma possibilidade de abrir um banco de dados .db (ao invés de criar o arquivo) pelo android studio utilizando o sqlite.

Ja criei um arquivo de dados .db com os dados e joguei dentro da pasta do dispositivo (data/data...etc), o banco de dados servirá apenas para consulta, imagino que seja no método OnCreate da classe do SQLiteOpenHelper que consiga abrir o banco, porém não tenho noção de como.

Comment: voce precisa criar o metodo para abrir dabases do teu helper sqlite normalmente, pois bem, se o helper for criar o db, ele vai criar na pasta **/data/user/0/com.seodominio.suaapp/databases**, dai basta voce sobrepor o arquivo que tem nessa pasta com o arquivo que vc criou e voilá, lembrando que deve ser igual ao que voce cria no helper, pois os metodos terão que pesquisar neles pelas suas colunas e etc.

Comment: Então foi esse o procedimento que eu fiz, ele cria o banco, mais queria saber se tem algum método que eu possa abrir ele referenciando-o em algum diretório, ao invés de criar e sobrepor.

Comment: fiquei boiando nessa... vc cria e/ou abre o db com os metodos do sqlitehelper, se vc quiser manipular esse arquivo vc teria de ter uma ferramenta para isso instalada no dispositivo ou preencher ele com os dados q vc precisa quando ele for criado usando um arquivo csv ou outro qualquer na pasta res/raw ou app/assets

Comment: Eu respondi essa pergunta que pode ser oq vc quer https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234894/carregando-um-banco-sqlite-criado-externamente/234960#234960

Answer (score 0):

Nativamente não tem como enviar um arquivo .db já populado. Eu também já pesquisei isso. Você tem algumas opções:

1) Usar uma library que faça isso (eu encontrei algumas, mas nunca utilizei)

2) Criar os inserts necessários durante a criação do banco, se não for muita coisa.

3) Baixar os dados de algum servidor pela internet na primeira execução do aplicativo e popular a base.