# Carregando um banco SQLite criado externamente

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou precisando usar um banco de dados Sqlite previamente criado, já com registros inseridos nele. Porém a unica forma que tinha feito até então, era quando a própria aplicação criava o banco, cujo, eu mesmo populava internamente na aplicação.

Agora eu tenho um banco SQLite com registros consideráveis e preciso usa-lo na minha aplicação, porém não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Olhei [este tutorial](http://diegorubin.com/2012/02/19/desenvolvimento-para-android-carregando-um-banco-criado-externamente), mas não obtive sucesso. Ao executar a aplicação, sempre disparava uma exceção com "Não foi possível copiar o arquivo".

Gostaria de saber uma forma de utilizar meu banco, SQLite, criado externamente na minha aplicação Android, não precisa seguir os princípios do tutorial acima.

Comment: Você disponibilizou o arquivo no local onde sua aplicação criaria ele? e deu permissão de leitura e escrita?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, no seu `build.gradle` (module:app)
Adicione a seguinte linha:

```
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
```

Vai nos ajudar a conectar com o banco.
Sincronize seu gradle depois disso.

Depois, no seu projeto, clique com o botão direito na pasta `app`, clique em new > folder > assets folder.

Dentro da pasta recém criada, crie mais uma pasta chamada "databases". Cole o banco que deseja usar dentro dessa pasta.

Agora, crie uma classe chamada `DatabaseOpenHelper`.

```
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "meubd.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Agora vamos instanciar e abrir a conexão.
Crie a classe `DatabaseAccess`;

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;

/**
 * Construtor privado
 * @param context
 */
DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

/**
 * Retorna um singleton de DatabaseAccess
 *
 * @param context
 */
public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Abre a conexão
 */
public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

/**
 * Fecha a conexão
 */
public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}
```

Crie os métodos que precisar dentro dessa classe(um `select`, por exemplo), abra a conexão na classe que você estiver usando 
`DatabaseAccess db = new DatabaseAccess()`

`db.open();`

Chame seu método:

`db.MetododeSelect();`

feche a conexão: 
`db.close();`

Comment: Cara não sei como agradecer, resolveu meus problemas :). Só alterei algum detalhe, mas pra atender gostos próprios mesmo, mas isso funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

No Android Studio 4.1 essa operação pode ser realizada utilizando-se o **Device File Explorer**.

1. Navegar até *data/data/`<`packagename`>`/databases/`<`database`>`.db*
2. Para exportar, basta selecionar o *database* e aplicar "Save as"
3. Para importar, use o mesmo procedimento anterior, escolhendo "Upload".

Answer (score 0):

Nativamente não tem como importar um banco SQL pré-carregado. As opções são:

1) Fazer uma reversa da base para gerar o DDL (script com os inserts) e usá-lo no Helper da sua aplicação quando criar as tabelas

2) Fazer um import usando algo como o tutorial que você postou, que usa o FileSystem para mover o arquivo para o local correto, ou usando libraries de terceiros. Ex: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

OBS: O tutorial que você publicou parece ter sido baseado em outro tutorial que já havia lido e teve boa aceitação no [StackOverFlow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/ship-an-application-with-a-database). Veja se tem alguma diferença: https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Uma outra opção mais complexa e interessante seria usar o Firebase e importar os dados de lá na primeira execução do aplicativo.

Answer (score 0):

Tem essa lib aqui que pode te ajudar, saiu recentemente no Android Arsenal

```
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6154
```